# In Quarto how can I show inline R code that is part of a YAML header

Tags: r, knitr, quarto

I am writing a tutorial in Quarto and I want to point out that you can use inline R code in the YAML header.  I want my students to see this:

You can automatically insert today's date with `` date: "`r Sys.Date()`" ``

Because the YAML is not using {r}, I can't find a way to tell knitr to not evaluate the `Sys.Date()` function.  Is there a way to display that code in the sentence without having to imbed an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick could be using the unicode representation `\u0060` of backticks.

````yaml
---
title: Showing Inline R code
engine: knitr
---

Insert today's date with ```date: "`r "\u0060r Sys.Date()\u0060" `" ```
````

[image: Escaped inline R code]

**Explanation:** Knitr will evaluate the expression `"\u0060r Sys.Date()\u0060"` in the inline R code and generate a markdown file containing,

````
---
title: Showing Inline R code
engine: knitr
---

Insert today's date with ```date: "`r Sys.Date()`" ```
````

which will be passed to pandoc then and pandoc will produce the expected output then.

Comment: Thank you @shafee.  That is cleaner than the other solution that I came up in my sleep: <code>date: &#34;&#96;r Sys.Date()&#96;&#34;</code>

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose the YAML with the inline R expression in double tick marks ``. You can also enclose it in three tickmarks to get in a separate line.

The code for the Quarto docs are on github and you can [check out there how they do it](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-web/blob/1f588ded1c9488afad5eb30a87792c945aed276f/docs/get-started/computations/rstudio.qmd#L235).

Note: Inline code expressions in quarto are now using curly brackets around the language name. For R it still works without, for any other language curly brackets are needed.

````
---
format: html
editor: source
---

You can automatically insert today's date with by including
the following in your YAML header: ``date: `{r} Sys.Date()` ``

OR

You can automatically insert today's date with by including
the following in your YAML header:

```
---
date: `{r} Sys.Date()`
---
```
````

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Try the YAML header that you suggested.  It does not work for me.  There needs to be quotes surrounding the inner backticks.  When you include them the sentence does not work.